# Testing a Rest controller post request

Tags: java, junit

So i have a method tha takes and user Id and a multipartFile and uploads it to aws and im trying to test it but i get and  error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand

this is the method to upload the file

```
 public void uploadUserProfileImage(@PathVariable("userProfileId")UUID userProfileId ,
                                       @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file){

        userProfileService.uploadUserProfileImage(userProfileId,file);

    }
```

and this is the test i came up with, im trying to learn how to test my methods.

```
@Test
    void uploadUserProfileImage() throws Exception {
        BufferedImage img;
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/main/java/images/bane.png"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "file", byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArryaImg = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        //given
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file",
                "file",
                MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE,
                byteArryaImg);

        UserProfileModel user = new UserProfileModel(UUID.randomUUID(), "luad", "ada");
        String userProfileId = user.getUserProfileId().toString();

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/{userProfileId}/image/upload")
                .file(file)
                .accept(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG))
                .andExpect(status()
                        .isOk());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you may use such as following;

```
MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("image-name", "mock-file.png", "image/jpeg", "image".getBytes());
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockRequest = fileUpload("/{userProfileId}/image/upload").file(mockMultipartFile)
```

you need to import fileUpluad method from;

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload;
```

then, just perform such as;

```
mockMvc.perform(mockRequest).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: i tried this the method fileUpload() is deprecated it says the same Not enough variable values available to expand

Comment: can you mention a little bit more about the spring boot version and jUnit version?

Comment: spring <version>2.5.3</version>  junit   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>

Comment: my spring boot version is 1.5.12 and JUnit 4 :) your version is very enhanced